# Why is Selenium not able to identify the WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to press the + icon present under Bedrooms. I even hard-coded a 5 seconds wait. The last line throws element not found exception. Please, help me.

```
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/VRACSearch-g294207-Reviews-Nairobi-Vacation_Rentals.html");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_2uJXqhFj']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[14]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Was your question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`.//div[text()='Bedrooms']//following-sibling::div/span/span[contains(@class,'ui_icon plus')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using css selector for this icon:

```
._1laeAPbS:nth-of-type(1) .plus
```